# Android Home Screen Maximum Height&Width for widget

Tags: android, widget

Is there a possible way to get the size of device's grid? (4x4 or 5x5).
With the code below, I can only get the dimension of the full screen. 
I've attached an image file for clarification.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had an appWidget that was 1x1 cell in size. I set it to 72dp x 72dp, and it was working fine.. But it seems like Google changed the widget dimension sizing formula from

```
(cells * 74) - 2
```

to

```
(cells * 70) - 30
```

So now the default size of my widget has to be 40dp x 40dp..

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#anatomy_determining_size

Comment: Thanx for the answer, but I meant the size of the red box not the widget itself. Do you know a way to find that area?